# Migrating 'openapi.Schema()' from drf-yasg to drf-spectacular

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, drf-yasg, drf-spectacular

I'm migrating from drf-yasg to drf-spectacular, using the [From drf-yasg to OpenAPI 3](https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/drf_yasg.html), and I've done most of my docs, but I have some problems triying to replace my old `openapi.Schema()`.

By the docs `Schema is not required and can be eliminated. Use a plain dict instead`, but I'm not sure how to fit this dict when you have nested objects, for example, my code originaly was:

```
    @swagger_auto_schema(
        operation_summary="Text",
        operation_description="More text",
        request_body=openapi.Schema(
            "body",
            "Body params",
            openapi.TYPE_OBJECT,
            properties={
                "params": openapi.Schema(
                    type=openapi.TYPE_ARRAY,
                    items=openapi.Items(
                        type=openapi.TYPE_OBJECT,
                        properties={
                            "param1": openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_INTEGER),
                            "param2": openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_STRING),
                        },
                    ),
                )
            },
        ),
        responses={
            200: openapi.Response(
                "Response",
                openapi.Schema(
                    "response",
                    type=openapi.TYPE_OBJECT,
                    properties={
                        "status": openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_STRING, default="ok"),
                        "details": openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_STRING),
                    },
                ),
            ),
        },
        tags=["example"],
```

I'm not sure how to deal with the `type=openapi.TYPE_OBJECT` and include the array type (I know about the `many=True` but again, not how to fit it in the dict).

By the docs, it should go something like this? But where I should use the `many=True` here for the array?

```
    request={
        "params": [
            "param1": OpenApiTypes.INT,
            "param2": OpenApiTypes.STR,
        ]
    },
```